# probability function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

have adiscreet random variable and cumulative distribution function ,how do i get the probability function,mean ,variance
x    1    2    3     4       5     6     7     8
F(x) 0.1  0.2  0.25   0.4    0.5   0.6  0.75   1

determine the probability function,f(x)=p(X=x),of x(2).
calculate E(X)  VAR(X) (4)
GIVEN THAT Y=2x+3,find the mean and variance of y(2)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** if $F$ is the cumulative density function of $X$ on $\Omega=\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $f$ its probability mass function, then
$$
\forall k \in \Omega,\quad F(k) = \sum_{i=1}^k f(i)
$$
(This is a special case of $F(x)=\mathbb{P}\!\left\{X\in(-\infty, x]\right\}$.) Now, express $f(k)$ as $F(k)-F(k-1)$...

For the expectation $\mathbb{E}X$, by definition
$$
\mathbb{E}X = \sum_{k=1}^n k \cdot f(k)
$$
and for the variance, also by definition
$$
\operatorname{Var}X = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - ( \mathbb{E}X )^2 = \mathbb{E}X = \sum_{k=1}^n k^2\cdot f(k) - \left(\sum_{k=1}^n k \cdot f(k)\right)^2.
$$

Finally, for $Y$, recall that the *expectation is a linear operator*: for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\mathbb{E}[aX+b] = a\mathbb{E}[X] + b.
$$
For the variance, you can either use the definition above (with $Y$ instead of $X$) to compute it directly, or use the following two properties of the variance:

- it is translation-invariant: for all $b\in\mathbb{R}$, $\operatorname{Var}(X+b) = \operatorname{Var}X$;
- it scales quadraticly: for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $\operatorname{Var}(aX) = a^2\operatorname{Var}X$.